# Find the Set substraction or the difference between the list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries as below , both are in different length.

```
list A = [{'key1':'001', 'key2':'AAA', 'key3':'BBB'}, 
              {'key1':'002', 'key2':'BBB', 'key3':'CCC'},
               {'key1':'003', 'key2':'XYZ', 'key3':'ZYX'}]

list B = [{'key1':'001', 'key2':'AAA', 'key3':'BBB'},
              {'key1':'002', 'key2':'ABX', 'key3':'GHT'}]
```

I want to do a List A - list B it should return me the list contains the newly added Dictionary ,and the dictionary in which any of the values are changed

Result of List A - List B would return as

```
List A - List B = [ {'key1':'003', 'key2':'XYZ', 'key3':'ZYX'},
                    {'key1':'002', 'key2':'BBB', 'key3':'CCC'}]
```

I different ways, Could any one please help me on this

Comment: What have you tried for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
list_A = [
    {'key1':'001', 'key2':'AAA', 'key3':'BBB'},
    {'key1':'002', 'key2':'BBB', 'key3':'CCC'},
    {'key1':'003', 'key2':'XYZ', 'key3':'ZYX'}
]

list_B = [
    {'key1':'001', 'key2':'AAA', 'key3':'BBB'},
    {'key1':'002', 'key2':'ABX', 'key3':'GHT'}
]                  



def list_subtraction(from_list, to_list):
    ''' Subtracts to_list from from_list'''
    list_c = []
    for i in list_A:
        if i not in list_B:
            list_c.append(i)
    return list_c            

print(list_subtraction(list_A, list_B))
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked like a charm and saved my day